# How to create a multi-select lookup relationship between two custom objects?

Tags: lookup, multi-select

While coding for Force.com please tell how to create a multi-select lookup relationship between two custom objects?

[![I am trying to achieve something like this][1]][1]

Comment: Do you want to have multiple users associated with one provisioning record?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve at the end of the day?